# Why can't this inherited class attribute be assigned to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I know in Ruby, unlike other languages, there is class method inheritance.

```
class A
  def self.filter_by
    "filter"
  end
end

class B < A
end

B.filter_by => "filter"
```

B's singleton class inherits methods from A's singleton class, and it appears to inherit the instance variables of those class methods:

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :filter_by
  end
end

class B < A    
end

B.filter_by = "filter"
A.filter_by = "no_filter" 
=> "no_filter" 
B.filter_by # B's value is not changed
=> "filter"
```

But it does not inherit the values:

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :filter_by
  end
end

class B < A
end

A.filter_by = "filter"
B.filter_by => nil
```

B did not inherit the value set to A's @filter_by instance variable.

It can be resolved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752641/ruby-class-instance-variables-and-inheritance) way using the built-in inherited hook, or in Rails you can use `class_attribute`:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  class_attribute :filter_by
end
class B < A
end 
A.filter_by = "filter"
 => "filter" 
B.filter_by # Now B's @filter_by inherited the value set in A's @filter_by
 => "filter"
```

But what I don't understand is why I cannot do this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  class_attribute :filter_by
end

class B < A
  filter_by= %w(user_id_is status_id_is task_category_id_is)
end
B.filter_by => nil
```

Why does it return nil in this situation and not in the other situation? In this case as well, I set a value on self when I declared B (which is the singleton object).

Comment: In your last example, which version of `A` is `B` inheriting from?

Comment: In the last example, the version of A used is class A < ActiveRecord::Base class_attribute :filter_by end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that in your last example, there is

1. A class attribute named `filter_by`(with corresponding `filter_by` and `filter_by=` methods (inherited from class A)
2. A locally scoped variable inside of class B called `filter_by`.

The variable `filter_by` is not available outside of the scoping, and is also not available inside `class B` methods of any kind. In `class B`, you've set this variable to the list of strings, but when you do `B.filter_by`, the method inherited from `class A` is called. This value has not yet been set, so `nil` is returned.

Had you done `self.filter_by = %w(...)` inside the class, then it would have accessed the method `filter_by=` and set the class attribute as you intended.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot `self.` when you assigned to the attribute. Ruby thought you were assigning to a local. Fix it with `self.`:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  class_attribute :filter_by
end

class B < A
  self.filter_by= %w(user_id_is status_id_is task_category_id_is)
end

B.filter_by => nil
=> ["user_id_is", "status_id_is", "task_category_id_is"]
```

Comment: Your example doesn't have `self` inside anywhere?

Comment: Oops, copied and forgot to modify. Fixed.