# Ruby class constants and inheritance mystery

Tags: ruby, class, constants, immutability

Why do the following two code snippets not produce the same output? The difference between `push` and `|=` is a tricky one. I suppose that `|=` being an assignment might make a difference? On top of that would constants actually be safe from change later on, I guess not?

The code comes from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752641/ruby-class-instance-variables-and-inheritance). You can see it [in action here](http://ideone.com/y1y35B).

```
class LibraryItem

  ATTRIBUTES = ['title', 'authors', 'location']

end

class LibraryBook < LibraryItem

  ATTRIBUTES.push('ISBN', 'pages']

end

puts LibraryItem::ATTRIBUTES
puts LibraryBook::ATTRIBUTES

> ["title", "authors", "location", "ISBN", "pages"]
> ["title", "authors", "location", "ISBN", "pages"]
```

and

```
class Foo

  ATTRIBUTES = ['title','authors','location']

end

class Bar < Foo

  ATTRIBUTES |= ['ISBN', 'pages']

end

puts Foo::ATTRIBUTES
puts Bar::ATTRIBUTES

> ["title", "authors", "location"]
> ["title", "authors", "location", "ISBN", "pages"]
```

Comment: In the first example, `ATTRIBUTES` refers to the **same** array in both cases, and modifying it in one place means the other will see the changes too. In the second one, you are creating a new array for `Bar` instead of changing the shared one, which results in the behavior you want.

Comment: So it's assigning that makes all the difference? That means if my class get's subclassed, any subclass can change a 'constant'?

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Ruby is an interpreted language.

Comment: @RyanBemrose Whoops, yeah. I meant to say the first raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants in ruby are a bit of a misnomer. Reassigning a constant produces a warning:

```
Foo=1
Foo=2
(irb):5: warning: already initialized constant Foo
```

But nothing stops you mutating the actual values themselves, which `push` does. If you want to prevent this happening, then you can freeze the array, i.e.

```
class LibraryItem    
  ATTRIBUTES = ['title', 'authors', 'location'].freeze
end
```

Attempts to mutate the array will now raise an exception. Only the array is frozen though, so you could do something like

```
LibraryItem::ATTRIBUTES.first.upcase!
```

(assuming you haven't got frozen string literals turned on) and that change will be allowed. I'm not aware of a way around that other than freezing the strings individually (or turning on frozen string literals for that file, on ruby 2.3 and above)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things quite a bit

Comment: To freeze each wouldn't be that hard -- you'd just do `= [ ... ].map(&:freeze!).freeze!`

Comment: Er, just `freeze`, not `freeze!`. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

In first example, `ATTRIBUTES` refer to the same array and you are modifying it. Hence,

```
puts LibraryItem::ATTRIBUTES
puts LibraryBook::ATTRIBUTES
```

produce same results.

While in second case, you are doing `a |= b` which is a shorthand for `a = a | b`. This will create a new array called `ATTRIBUTES` for class `Bar`. Hence,

```
puts Foo::ATTRIBUTES
puts Bar::ATTRIBUTES
```

produce different result.

You can read more about **Ruby Assignment Operator** in this question. [Ruby |= assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569039/ruby-assigment-operator)

**EDIT**

Ruby arrays implements a small collection of set operation with `&`, `|` operators.

Single Pipe, `|` perform union operation i.e. adds only unique elements.

```
a = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
a |= [:baz, :buz] # => [:foo, :bar, :baz, :buz]
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I don't need brushing up on assignment operators, however on the concept of _constants_ I do apparently...